# Cannot find serial port support in Qt 6.3.2

Tags: qt, qt-creator

For some reason I should use Qt6 for my project. I need serial port functionality but Qt Creator cannot find corresponding module. The following error is raised:
**Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: serialport**. My .pro file includes serialport - it seems to me that the problem is in the absence of this module. Also I don't corresponding examples projects.
I tried to install libqt5serialport5 and libqt5serialport5-dev using commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5serialport5
sudo apt-get install libqt5serialport5-dev
```

but it didn't help. Please explain how to add serial port module to my Qt6 installation.
Below is information about my installation:

```
Qt Creator 8.0.2
Based on Qt 6.3.2 (GCC 10.3.1 20210422 (Red Hat 10.3.1-1), x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved very simple. Use Qt MaintenanceTool using which allows remove/update or install modules.

Answer (score 0):

Qt Serial Port is now a separate library that must be installed separately from the main Qt installation. You can do this from the MaintanceTool. Find it under your installed Qt version under "Additional Libraries". Once installed, you should be good to go (you still need to specify "serialport" in your modules in your project file).